# Validation for error

Tags: c++, regex, runtime-error

While developing my personal library I stumbled upon what I think is an error inside libstdc++6.

Because I'm quite sure this library has been reviewed by a lot of much higher skilled people than I am I came here to validate my finding and get assistance on further steps.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::string uri = "http://example.com/test.html";
        std::regex reg(...);
        std::smatch match;
        std::regex_match(uri, match, reg);
        for(auto& e: match)
        {
                std::cout<<e.str() <<std::endl;
        }
}
```

I have written a regex to parse a URL into

- Protocol
- User/Pass (optional)
- Host
- Port (optional)
- Path (optional)
- Query (optional)
- Location (optional)

I used the following regex (in c++):

```
std::regex reg("^(.+):\\/\\/(.+@)?([a-zA-Z\\.\\-0-9]+)(:\\d{1,5})?([^?\\n\\#]*)(\\?[^#\\n]*)?(\\#.*)?$");
```

This worked quite fine in a online tester and MSVC++ 2015 Update 3 but fails on my build host where the host part matches both host and path.

Buildhost:

> g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
>
> libstdc++6:amd64 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2

I consider this an error because if I change the regex to this:

```
std::regex reg("^(.+):\\/\\/(.+@)?([a-zA-Z\\.0-9\\-]+)(:\\d{1,5})?([^?\\n\\#]*)(\\?[^#\\n]*)?(\\#.*)?$");
```

It works fine althought it should behave exactly the same.

Failing regex: https://ideone.com/7n2JdK

Working regex: https://ideone.com/6NMPUW

Do I miss something really important here or is this an error within libstdc++6 ?

The only difference is on the char class:

```
[a-zA-Z\\.\\-0-9] // not working
[a-zA-Z\\.0-9\\-] // working
```

Comment: Perhaps you would like to point out the difference between the two regexes, or do you expect everyone to compare them, character by characters?

Comment: There is no need to check char by char. This is clearly a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly a bug because `"[.\\-0]"` should be parsed as a character class matching a character that is either `.` or `-` (since the hyphen is escaped with a literal `\`) or a `0`. For an unknown reason, the hyphen is parsed as a range operator and the `[a-zA-Z\\.\\-0-9]+` subexpression becomes equal to `[a-zA-Z.-0-9]+`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8tcFNU/1).

The second expression works because a `-` at the end of the character class (and at its start) is always parsed as a literal hyphen.

Another example of the same bug:

```
std::string uri = "%";
std::regex reg(R"([$\-&])");
std::smatch match;
std::regex_match(uri, match, reg);
for(auto& e: match)
{
   std::cout<< e.str() <<std::endl;
}
```

The `[$\-&]` regex should not match `%`, it should match `$`, `-` or `&`, but for whatever reason, the `%` (that is between `$` and `&` in the ASCII table) [is still matched](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/757705257ea52089).

Comment: So what to do next ?
Where can i file this bug to get it fixed ?

Comment: You may just always place the hyphen at the start or end of the character class.

Comment: Sure but shouldn't this bug get fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is not a bug but I think this has to do with the basic RE specification.

One should be aware about the specifics of a literal `-` (hyphen), *especially* if one wants to match such a thing. Quoth `re_format(7)` (the first sentence):

> To include a literal
>        `-`, make it the first or last character, or the second endpoint of a range.  To use a literal `-` as the first end-
>        point of a range, enclose it in `[.` and `.]` to make it a collating element (see below).  With the exception of
>        these and some combinations using `[` (see next paragraphs), all other special characters, including `\`, lose their
>        special significance within a bracket expression.

I.e. escaping a hyphen and expect it to match as a character is exactly not what the man page sais how to match a literal hyphen.

Comment: This is related to POSIX regex flavor, while the [default std::regex flavor ECMAScript](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/). If it were POSIX, the `"[\\]"` regex  would be parsed as a backslash pattern, but it [fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adb3d3c3635dd74a). There is no such thing as a "basic RE specification", there are a lot of regex flavors and POSIX is one of the regex flavor types.